# Как получить значение из блока измененые при клике за пределами этого события?

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите начинающему! Есть задача: при клике на стрелочку появляется меню выбора количества гостей.
Это я реализовал так:

```
$("#dropdown-guests-button").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".dropdown-guests").toggleClass("dropdown-guests_default");
  $(".dropdown-guests__enter").toggleClass("dropdown-guests__enter_default");
  $(".dropdown-guests__choice").toggleClass("dropdown-guests__choice_activated");
});
```

Далее, при клике на плюс или минус меняется количество

Реализация нажатия на плюс, минус делает обратное:

```
$("#adult-plus").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#adult-result").text(function(text) {
    return String(parseInt(text) + 1);
  });
});
```

Далее мне нужно отталкиваться от измененных значений. Вот тут проблема. Значения я меняю, но не могу дальше с ними работать, не знаю где они хранятся.

В блоке значение изменено, но при запросе вне события, например вот так

```
let count = $("#adult-result").text()
console.log(count) - тут выведет 0, хотя значение поменялось
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значения нужны для дальнейшей работы с кнопками очистить и применить, например, при количестве больше 1, нужно показать кнопку очистить и с помощью нее сбрасывать все на 0. Также "применить" должна делать сбор данных из всех полей и считать общее количество, далее подставлять значение в дефолтный инпут и скрывать блок с выбором.

Comment: Без html разметки сложно сказать что-то определенное. А еще лучше - воспроизводимый пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заинтересовал ваш вопрос, по этому хочу реализовать..

```js
$('.select').find('.-list .-option').each(function(){ // Проходим по всем .-option
  let data = { // Они содержат в себе атрибуты `data-`, получим их значения в массив:
    min: Number($(this).attr('data-min')),
    val: Number($(this).attr('data-val')) || 0,
    max: Number($(this).attr('data-max'))
  };
  
  // Некая защита, чтобы не было значения больше максимального или меньше минимального.
  if(data.val <= data.min) data.val = data.min;
  if(data.val >= data.max) data.val = data.max;
  
  // Так как "изначальная" запись `.-option` у нас упращённая, то мы наполняем её содержимым, для того же изменения значений.
  $(this).html('<div class="-title">'+$(this).attr('data-title')+'</div>\
    <div class="-input">\
      <div class="-button'+(data.val <= data.min ? ' --disabled' : '')+'" data-action="minus">-</div>\
      <div class="-value">'+data.val+'</div>\
      <div class="-button'+(data.val >= data.max ? ' --disabled' : '')+'" data-action="plus">+</div>\
    </div>');
});

// Обработчик кнопок..
$('.select').on('click', '.-button', function(){
  if(!$(this).hasClass('--disabled')) { // Если кнопка не имеет "запрет" на себе, то работаем дальше..
    let action = $(this).attr('data-action'); // Получаем "действие" кнопки
    if(action === 'minus' || action === 'plus') { // Если это кнопка `-` или `+`, что находится в .-option, то
      let option = $(this).closest('.-option'), // Получаем этот самый .-option..
          data = { //.. и его data значения
            min: Number(option.attr('data-min')),
            val: Number(option.attr('data-val')),
            max: Number(option.attr('data-max')),
            step: Number(option.attr('data-step')) || 1
          };
      // Если нажат "минус", то отнимаем число равное step (если оно есть, если нет то step == 1), если "плюс", то прибавляем step. (аналог как у input[type=number]
      data.val = action === 'minus' ? data.val - data.step : data.val + data.step;
      // Тут та же защита, чтобы не вылезать за приделы min или max
      data.val = data.val < data.min ? data.min : data.val > data.max ? data.max : data.val;
      
      // Тут механика, которая "блокирует" кнопку, если value дошёл до min или max
      if(data.val > data.min && action === 'plus') 
        option.find('.-button[data-action="minus"]').removeClass('--disabled');
      if(data.val <= data.min && action === 'minus') 
        option.find('.-button[data-action="minus"]').addClass('--disabled');
      if(data.val < data.max && action === 'minus') 
        option.find('.-button[data-action="plus"]').removeClass('--disabled');
      if(data.val >= data.max && action === 'plus') 
        option.find('.-button[data-action="plus"]').addClass('--disabled');
        
      // Когда мы выше меняем value, то переписываем значения.
      option.attr('data-val', data.val);
      option.find('.-input .-value').text(data.val);
      // И если это дело меняется впервые, то мы показываем кнопку "Применить"
      if($('.select').find('.-button[data-action="apply"]').hasClass('--disabled')) $('.select').find('.-button[data-action="apply"]').removeClass('--disabled');
    }
    
    // Это действия кнопок "Очистить" и "Применить"
    if(action === 'clear' || action === 'apply') {
        if(action === 'clear') { // Если нажата "очистить", то мы всем -option ставим value = 0
        $('.select').find('.-list .-option').attr('data-val', 0);
        $('.select').find('.-list .-option .-value').text(0);
      }
        NumGuests(); // Если нажата какая-то из этих кнопок, то мы выполняем функцию ниже..
    }
  }
});

// ..Вот эту
function NumGuests() {
  // Это то самое, что выводим в "шапку селектора" сообщение о количистве "гостей".
    let guests = 0, text = '', output = {};
  // Проходим по всем .-option и получаем значение
  $('.select').find('.-list .-option').each(function(){
    let val = Number($(this).attr('data-val')) || 0;
    output[$(this).attr('data-title')] = val;
    guests += val; // Прибавляем к guests
  });
  
  // Если гостей больше 0, то..
  if(guests > 0) {
    text = guests+' '+declOfNum(guests, ['гость', 'гостя', 'гостей']); // Оформляем сообщение
    $('.select').find('.-button[data-action="clear"]').removeClass('--disabled'); // Показываем кнопку "Очистить"
  } else {
    text = 'Сколько гостей'; // Дефолтное сообщение о количистве гостей, даём понять пользователю, что нужно заполнить этот "селектор"
    $('.select').find('.-button[data-action="clear"]').addClass('--disabled'); // Скрываем кнопку "Очистить", ибо зачем она нам, ведь гостей нет..
  }
  //
  $('.select').find('.-label .-title').text(text);
  $('.select').attr('data-guests', guests);
  $('.select').find('.-button[data-action="apply"]').addClass('--disabled'); // прячем кнопку "применить", ибо мы только что изменили данные
  //
  console.clear();
  console.info(output); // Выходные данные в виде объекта
  $('.select').find('.-output').val(JSON.stringify(output)); // Мы добавляем эти данные в input, который находится в теле селектора, предварительно "конвертим" объект в строку,  на сервере мы можем их распарсить.
} NumGuests();

// Этот код склоняет фразу `n гост[ь,я,ей]`, тем самым делая селектор "живее".
function declOfNum(number,titles){ 
  cases = [2,0,1,1,1,2]; 
  return titles[(number%100>4 && number%100<20)? 2 : cases[(number%10<5)?number%10:5]]; 
}

// Это обработчик открытия\закрытия дропменю
$('.select .-label').on('click', function() {
    $('.select').toggleClass('--drop');
});

// А это обработчик закрытия дропменю, если клик был вне его области
$(document).mouseup(function(e){
  if(!$('.select.--drop').is(e.target) && $('.select.--drop').has(e.target).length === 0) $('.select.--drop').removeClass('--drop');
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Roboto,Open Sans,Helvetica Neue,"Noto Sans Armenian","Noto Sans Bengali","Noto Sans Cherokee","Noto Sans Devanagari","Noto Sans Ethiopic","Noto Sans Georgian","Noto Sans Hebrew","Noto Sans Kannada","Noto Sans Khmer","Noto Sans Lao","Noto Sans Osmanya","Noto Sans Tamil","Noto Sans Telugu","Noto Sans Thai",sans-serif;
}

.select {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.select .-label {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #929197;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select .-label .-title {opacity: .65;}

.select .-label .-arrow {
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  opacity: .65;
  position: relative;
}

.select .-label .-arrow:hover {opacity: 1;}

.select .-label .-arrow::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border-left: 2px solid #929197;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #929197;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -75%) rotate(-45deg);
  z-index: 1;
}

.select .-dropdown {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #929197;
  border-top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.select.--drop .-label {border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;}
.select.--drop .-label .-arrow {transform: rotate(180deg);}
.select.--drop .-dropdown {display: block;}

.select .-list {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.select .-option {width: 100%;}

.select .-button {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.select .-option .-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #96969e;
  color: #96969e;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.select .-option:not(:last-child) {margin-bottom: 5px;}

.select .-option .-value {
  width: 3ch;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.select .-option .-button.--disabled {opacity: .45;}

.select .-label,
.select .-option,
.select .-option .-input,
.select .-change {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.select .-change {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.select .-change .-button {opacity: .65;}
.select .-change .-button:hover {opacity: 1;}
.select .-change .-button.--disabled {visibility: hidden;}

.select .-change .-button[data-action="apply"] {color: #7e47f9;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <div class="-label">
    <div class="-title">Сколько гостей</div>
    <div class="-arrow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="-dropdown">
    <div class="-list">
      <div class="-option" data-min="0" data-val="0" data-max="10" data-title="Взрослые"></div>
      <div class="-option" data-min="0" data-val="0" data-max="5" data-title="Дети"></div>
      <div class="-option" data-min="0" data-val="0" data-max="5" data-title="Младенцы"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="-change">
      <div class="-button" data-action="clear">Очистить</div>
      <div class="-button" data-action="apply">Применить</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" class="-output" name="select">
</div>
```

UPD: Добавил комментарии к коду, описывающие работу скрипта.

Смотреть "На весь экран".